# 3d modelling loading , updating and rendering in java

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

i am new to java 3d. i have encountered a situation like , i want to load ready made developed 3d model of any object [as an example shoe]  developed in 3d modeling software like 3d studio max or Maya in my java program , update its texture or color properties etc. then render it and then display the updated model to the end user.

so i am asking all the 3d experts how should i proceed ahead to accomplish my goal ?
which input should i load into my program ?
how can i update the loaded model  , render it and display the updated model to the end user ?

**in simple story , i want to give my users ability to modify 3d model by their interactions as such ,
they provided 3d model of shoe for example in default colors and textures & some fields like sole color , if they choose color red then the loaded 3d model's sole is colored red (i.e. updated) and then displayed to end user with red color rubber sole shoe instead of default color shoe.**

please, advice me to accomplish my goal.

Comment: What have you done? Do you have the model loaded and displayed already? What have you tried? How do you load the models?

Comment: Not a programming question -- no source code shown

Comment: @TheBlastOne have you read my question carefully ? i have clearly written my intension.

Comment: @DariuszWawer i just started this problem to solve and now i am researching, if you can help me . i have 3d artist already whoc can develope model in modelling software ? how should i go ahead for given scenario ? any book ? tutorial ? etc.

Comment: @Mihir http://bit.ly/X35loa

Comment: @DariuszWawer i have succesfully loaded the obj file of 3d model in my java canvas3D. now i come to know that the thing i am looking for is called Texture Mapping , can you guide me about it ? right now i am learning 3d maths to simplify learning of this technique. am i going in to right direction ?

Comment: Which 3D model formats have you tried? Maybe the one(s) you've tried haven't stored the texture information, or they've been exported wrong, or you haven't put the texture in the same location as the 3D model file. Also consider looking into a book on Java 3D, I know there are at least several books out there and maybe your local library or bookstore would have one.

Comment: When I learned Java3D I learned it on the internet and it took FOREVER. Then when I started doing iOS development I bought an OpenGL ES book for like 20$ US and I read the whole book in a couple of days. If you are serious about Java3D then trust me, buy a book.

Comment: As a warning, do not use comments to ask people to answer your question. This is extremely annoying, and I've removed all of the ones you left.

Comment: @Brad larson why this is extremely annoying ? there is no way in SO , i can invite specific user to help me answer my question, i don't understand the policy of most powered users of so of misusing their power , instead of focusing of learning users focusing on non sense matters for example i am expecting your expertise here and instead of giving me what i want what you have done ? removed all of my invitation.

Comment: @Mihir - People should come to your questions of their own free will. These are annoying, because the comments have nothing to do with the answers and questions you are leaving them on, and you are imposing on these users by creating notifications in their inbox every time you do this. Everyone here is a volunteer, and they help when they find the time to do so. There is a very specific reason why we've rejected adding any sort of notification system to contact specific users, because it would rapidly be abused by everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so first of all, complex objects are usually created using some 3D editing software like Blender or Art of Illusion. These programs can output the object into several different file formats, the most common being the .obj file format:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Another common format is .3ds, which in my experience is a lot more work than it's worth. They do make a .3ds file loader for Java3D, the page can be found here:

- http://www.starfireresearch.com/services/java3d/inspector3ds.html

My advice for you is to just use the .obj file format, it is a lot easier to use. You can also just make your own parser for it which is not as hard as it sounds. This way you know exactly how your object is being loaded into the environment. Java does come with it's own parser, instructions on how to use it are here:

- http://www.vrupl.evl.uic.edu/LabAccidents/java3d/lesson08/indexa.html

I have had a lot of trouble with files exported with Blender while using this file format unfortunately, they may have fixed the problem by now but I'm not sure. When I used to do a lot more 3D stuff I just used Art of Illusion, even know Blender is a lot more powerful. Blender can be run on a Mac but is a lot smoother on windows with the proper setup. Good luck! If you need some example code let me know and I would be more than happy to post some for you.

Art of Illusion:

- http://www.artofillusion.org
- http://www.artofillusion.org/documentation#

Blender:

- http://www.blender.org
- http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/

Im not sure how you want the user to be able to change the object. If you want them to be able to change the color, or the type of shoe or whatnot that is not a huge deal. If you want the user to be able to change the lace length or something where you are changing the actual object's structure, that requires an in depth knowledge of 3D structure. If you want to change a color, just change the material. If you want to be able to change the type of shoe, just load a different shoe object. I hope this was helpful for you.

In the comments, you also talk about texture mapping, which in my experience is a lot easier to do in Blender than it is to do in Art of Illusion. I would probably use blender to accomplish this:

- http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV

John

Comment: thanks for your valuable input, let me research on it and i will get back to you asap.

Comment: do you know jMonkeyEngine ?

Comment: I know of it but I don't use it. I have heard it is pretty easy to use and it is a lot more advanced than Java3D

Comment: now i have a concrete question for you. i hope you will help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want the user to select a different texture/color, right?

Then have a look at the Java3D tutorials out there, e.g. this one: http://www.java3d.org/tutorial.html

I further guess your shoe is actually a 2-part model, i.e. just the sole should get another color while the rest might get a different texture, right?

In that case, you'd need 2 models/shapes, each with its own appearance. Then, for example, alter the soles appearance as you like, e.g. by assigning a different material or changing the material's color.

Comment: yes i want as a user , first you will be provided with default 3d shoe model , for example white textures with white colors , black sole , white shoelace , white eyelet and you have option to change the default colors , so if you select yellow color for shoelace and red for eyelet , black for texture and press preview the default model is updated in appearance and result displayed to the result as they provided when choosing various options in previous sense.

Comment: @Mihir Though it may be late just curious to know if you find a direction on this. If yes, please share what technique did you use to render, update and reproduce 3D models